# fluent wait in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

please help me with implementing FluentWait using nightwatch.js
how can I use it??

in my project I have global.js containing:

```
waitForConditionPollInterval : 300,
    waitForConditionTimeout : 5000,
```

but this is not FluentWait??

And the second question is how to use variables from global.js in test scripts ??
for example, if I have code like this:

```
this.typeLoginAndSubmit = function() {
        browser
            .waitForElementVisible(loginPageSelectors.loginField, 5000)
            .setValue(loginPageSelectors.loginField, 'login')
            .waitForElementVisible(loginPageSelectors.loginSubmit, 5000)
            .click(loginPageSelectors.loginSubmit)
        return browser;
```

the nightwatch methods like "waitForElementVisible" has forced me to give ms value ?? so how and when I can use global.js configuration??

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a variable to the js.

```
 var global=require('global.js');

 browser
        .waitForElementVisible(loginPageSelectors.loginField, global.timeout);
```

or

just assign `var timeout=5000;` before all actions as the script you run is javascript

then use it

```
browser.waitForElementVisible(loginPageSelectors.loginField,timeout);
```